Decentralization status of rollups with a single validator
This is a question about the decentralization status of Ethereum rollups.
Based on what I can see on L2Beat, most rollups are currently at Stage 0, meaning they have two more stages to go before they become mature, decentralized networks.
This is what they say about Optimism:

Funds can be frozen if the centralized validator goes down. Users cannot produce blocks themselves and exiting the system requires new block production

Does this mean that rollups like Optimism are run by a single validator today?
And if yes, do they plan to keep it like this? Or can a rollup become decentralized even if it is run by a single validator?

While full decentralization offers numerous advantages in terms of security, resilience, and inclusivity, it also presents significant challenges and trade-offs. These include increased technical complexity, the need for sophisticated incentive structures, potential scalability issues, and the risk of higher operational costs. Achieving the right balance requires careful design, ongoing adjustments, and a focus on maintaining both security and efficiency as the network evolves.
From optimism-arbitrum-pt2-decentralization

While the security implications of decentralizing the roles of
sequencers, proposers, and validators should not be neglected, there
are also meaningful trade-offs or challenges to decentralizing rollup
operators such as:

A distributed set of sequencers may add to transaction latency or could collect MEV. A core benefit of having a centralized sequencer
is the ability to provide users with fast transaction confirmations
(assuming they are trusted not to re-order transactions). Transaction
latency is minimized under this approach since the ordering of
transactions is known once published to the Sequencer feed on L2
before they are batched to the L1. Optimism & Arbitrum’s sequencers
are currently trusted not to collect MEV, but with a distributed set
of sequencers, some could potentially front-run or sandwich user
transactions or else they would need to come to consensus on
transaction ordering, which could add latency to transactions and harm
the core UX advantage of having near-instant transaction receipts or
result in greater overhead costs for the rollup.

Permissionless validation may subject the rollup to delay attacks. The security of the rollup requires just one honest
verifier to check that the proposer posted the correct L2 state on
mainnet (1-of-N honesty assumption). While having more parties that
can submit fraud proofs is an important redundancy for security,
permissionless validation where anyone can submit a fraud proof would
potentially subject rollups to Denial-of-Service attacks from
malicious parties aiming to delay finalization of transactions on the
L1.



From the same article, they mention about the trade offs:

Several different approaches to decentralizing sequencers are being
explored, some of which include making changes to the ordering
algorithms and sequencer selection methodology (i.e.,
Proof-of-Authority, auction-based, stake-based using own rollup token,
distributed validator technology, etc.) and changes to the network
architecture or adoption of other technologies that may outsource
certain responsibilities to other protocols (i.e., based rollups or
shared sequencing models). The different approaches will have
different economic and structural implications for rollups including
MEV protection, governance, and interoperability or composability
across multiple rollup chains. Research is still being conducted
across these approaches to decentralize the sequencer on how to
effectively manage some of the security trade-offs, overhead costs and
UX considerations (we will explore some of these approaches in greater
detail in a separate report).

Optimistic rollups have low costs. what do you think happens if it implements full decentralization:

Decentralizing the role of the sequencer means multiple entities can propose and validate batches. This requires more sophisticated coordination and consensus mechanisms, potentially increasing operational costs.Ensuring all sequencers are synchronized and managing disputes efficiently can introduce additional network communication costs.

Decentralized systems need to provide sufficient economic incentives for participants to act honestly and efficiently. This could mean higher rewards for sequencers and validators, which could be funded by higher transaction fees.

Decentralization requires robust security measures to protect against attacks. Implementing protection for attacks will be costly.

The process of reaching consensus among multiple sequencers and validators can be slower and less efficient, possibly leading to higher costs.



Most of the rollups are in the early stages, where certain power is controlled by centralized actors: block production, upgradability, etc. But this is only an intermediate stage before protocol will be technically mature and well battle-tested (no security issues!). Then rollup may decentralize the sequencer, which definitely helps with the censorship resistance.
But regardless of the sequencer centralization, rollup must inherit censorship resistance from L1. And for this special mechanism is required. One example of how to solve the problem is zkSync Lite, where the sequencer is centralized, but user may request transaction execution directly from Ethereum. Then if the sequencer didn't process a transaction for a certain amount of time, the rollup switch to 'exodus mode'. In the exodus, rollup freezes the state and users can claim funds from Ethereum permissions.

The future plans for these rollups may involve transitioning to a more decentralized model.
It is important to consider that a rollup can potentially become decentralized even if it is initially run by a single validator, especially with the development of shared, decentralized sequencers.
This shift could address issues of censorship, MEV extraction, liveness, and introduce cross-rollup composability, ultimately leading to a more decentralized and secure network.

[E]very major L2 rollup project has, so far, found it more convenient,
cheaper, and user-friendly to run a centralized sequencer.

More information on centralized sequencers:
https://www.binance.com/en/research/analysis/ethereums-rollups-are-centralized-a-look-into-decentralized-sequencers
